# ApacheCamel - How to get HttpRequest and HttpReponse from exchange after HttpCopoment

Tags: apache-camel

How to get HttpRequest and HttpReponse from exchange after HttpCopoment?
Any hints or ideas are more than welcome

Below is the code example

```
        from("direct:restendpoint").routeId("direct_restendpoint")
            .to("https://<URL_SERVICE>")
            .process(exchange -> {
                String responseCode = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode").toString();
                //How to get httpRequest and httpResponse here?
            })
```

Comment: Did you already try `HttpServletResponse servletResponse = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletResponse.class);`?

Comment: exchange.getIn().getBody() ->class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream
2023-01-31 11:41:35.965  INFO 4308 --- [meSheetIntopic]] c.v.d.OutOdataServiceRouter              : servletResponse ->null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in this JIRA:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-19077

HttpServletRequest/Response are *only* for servlet components, eg `camel-servet` or `camel-jetty` and not for HTTP clients. So you cannot get hold of servlet with a HTTP client.